# Why aren't primary and secondary coils of a transformer overlapped over each other?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I am aware that soft iron core present in a transformer does prevent flux leakage.

But practically there is some non-negligible flux leakage nonetheless.
Why not then just overlap the coils over each other, so that (almost) ALL magnetic field lines of primary enter the secondary coil?

Is the benefit insignificant, or does it introduce new problems of its own? Does it in-fact worsen the efficiency? I'm so confused.

(Also, if you have enough (1000) reputation, please add "transformers", and/or "flux leakage" as a tag here; I can't believe they don't already exist)

Comment: What do you mean? In all the transformers that I've disassembled, the secondary was wound on top of the primary.

Comment: Hi Vivek. Physics books sometimes show the coils separated but I think this is just for clarity. In the real world the coils are always overlapped for exactly the reasons you describe.

Comment: This question might be a better fit on [Electrical engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The laminated soft iron core isn't just to help prevent flux leakage. It also greatly increases the flux itself and is important for the transmission of power from primary to secondary when there is a load. To understand why calls for a fuller treatment of transformers than a high school treatment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might be that you're being misled by diagrams like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/64/Transformer3d_col3.svg/440px-Transformer3d_col3.svg.png):

[image]

The windings on the core are drawn like this for conceptual clarity rather than to show how transformers are actually *constructed*. The windings are often coaxial like in [this](http://images.books24x7.com/bookimages/id_9293/fig4-1.jpg) drawing for example:

[image]

You might find [this segment](https://youtu.be/2HgS6gvokEI?t=126) of "How It's Made", showing the construction of transformers for McIntosh audio amplifiers, interesting.